# How to use CGAL::read_ply_points() to read binary ply files?

Tags: io, cgal

A new user of CGAL here.
I am currently trying out the example "registration_with_OpenGR.cpp"
https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/doc/master/Point_set_processing_3/Point_set_processing_3_2registration_with_OpenGR_8cpp-example.html

It seems that the function CGAL::read_ply_points() that is used to read ply files does not work on binary format, but it works when a ASCII ply file is given. Is there any extra flag that I need to set when reading binary ply files?

here is my current code for reading ply files.

```
#include <CGAL/property_map.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> K;
typedef K::Point_3 Point_3;
typedef K::Vector_3 Vector_3;
typedef std::pair<Point_3, Vector_3> Pwn;
typedef CGAL::First_of_pair_property_map<Pwn> Point_map;
typedef CGAL::Second_of_pair_property_map<Pwn> Normal_map;

namespace params = CGAL::parameters;

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    const char* fname1 = "data/reference.ply";
    const char* fname2 = "data/1.ply";
    std::vector<Pwn> pwns1, pwns2;
    std::ifstream input(fname1);
    if (!input ||
        !CGAL::read_ply_points(input, std::back_inserter(pwns1),
            CGAL::parameters::point_map(CGAL::First_of_pair_property_map<Pwn>()).
            normal_map(Normal_map())))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: cannot read file " << fname1 << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    input.close();
    input.open(fname2);
    if (!input ||
        !CGAL::read_ply_points(input, std::back_inserter(pwns2),
            CGAL::parameters::point_map(Point_map()).
            normal_map(Normal_map())))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: cannot read file " << fname2 << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    input.close();
    std::cerr << "SUCCESS" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give std::ios_base::binary to your stream constructor:
`std::ifstream input(fname1,std::ios_base::binary);`